# Trying to grasp relationships in core data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, entity, relationship

I am trying to understand core data relationships.  I have two entities.  One is called **Driver**, which has a (car driver's) name, age, gender.  The other entity is called **Cars** which has a cars Make, model, etc..

There is one **driver** for many **cars**.
There is an inverse relationship for **cars** to **drivers** (if I recall correctly)

I make a subclass of **NSManagedObject** for each entity..  and then I try to setvalues, and execute.

some pseudo code:

```
Driver *thisDriver = [NSEntityDescription ...
Car *thisCar= [NSEntityDescription ...
[thisCar setMake@"ford"];
// etc..

[thisDriver setName:@"bob"];
// etc..
[thisDriver setCar:thisCar];  // THIS PART NO GOOD =(
```

I noticed there was a method "**setCar**" within **thisCar**.. which accepted a driver variable..
It seems odd to set the parent from the child and not the other way around.  It makes sense to me that I create a number of anonymous instances of **Car** in an **NSSet**, and then store those into a **Driver**..  then save that.

Also, when I fetch a **Driver**..  how do I get all of the associated **Cars** for it?  I am able to fetch **Cars**, and get the **driver**, but not the other way around..

Maybe I'm thinking too much in terms of a traditional database where you use a foreign key to get all records for a related table?  It should be fairly similar though, right?

[image: this is how my core data looks. not my screenshot though]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you want a driver to have multiple cars, which means you need toMany relationship between Drivers and Cars. Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
[myDriver addCarObject:newCar];
```

Comment: I did create a to many relationship.. but I didn't see that function generated in my Driver class..  Perhaps I created my relationship incorrectly?  It had the double arrow and everything?  is there a way to drop in a set of cars into a driver?

Comment: It sounds like the relationship isn't correct. Can you post a pic of your Car and Driver relationship from your datamodel?

Comment: I'm away from my mac.  I'll come back to it later today.  it looks exactly like this though

location being driver, and checkin being cars

http://media.amazonwebservices.com/CoreData-Model.png

Comment: Was the relations ship to toOne at one point and got changed? If so, did you regenerate your model classes? Also, when you do something like "[myDriver add" what code completion options show?

Comment: I will come back to this when I get back on my computer later today.  I don't want to make any false assumptions.

Comment: it was the way i was naming my relationships which was confusing me

Comment: Hey, I am glad you found your answer :)